# capybara-webkit driver hangs out when running javascript tests in CI servers

Tags: capybara-webkit

When I run my integration tests marked with `js: true` in my local it works just fine, but when I run them in any CI integration server they hangout until it times out. Is there any known problem with webkit javascript driver? Is there any driver recommended for CI servers as well?